# How to install gmail desktop app

Tags: gmail

How to install gmail desktop app in ubuntu 20.10.i recently changes from windows to ubutntu .I want download gmail desktop app

Comment: What GMail desktop app? Pretty sure there's no official client from Google.

Comment: are you use Kubuntu or Ubuntu?

Comment: if you are use Ubuntu you can install it from your app store in Ubuntu for example i use Kubuntu and i install my gmail app from Discover (Kubuntu default app store)

Comment: this one? https://snapcraft.io/gmail-desktop

Comment: In case you are using chrome or chromium, you can create a desktop shortcut for a website, and use it as a standalone app.

Answer (score 2):

Thunderbird Mail is the default email client on Ubuntu installed by default and adding gmail to it is very straightforward.

All the server settings load very simply and cleanly without any real need for additional user intervention or complex configuration.

You will find it by pressing the left <kbd>Windows</kbd> key and start typing `Thunderbird` or clicking on the 9 dot (Bento) menu icon bottom left in the dock.